# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : & invalid label errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call and it returns something like, a JSON object;

```
{
id: 6,
success: "true"
}
```

My ajax call is :

```
window.foobar = function(foo){
    $.ajax({
            url: "http://foobar.com/sites/foo/",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
}
```

This ajax call is cross site call.
On `chrome` it gives:  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`
On `firefox` it gives:

```
invalid label
http://localhost:8080/sites/foo/?callback=jsonp1324336100888&_=1324336100894
Line 1
```

But when I calling from the `same domain` it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are claiming to support JSONP, you need to actually support it. Your code is valid JSON, but it is not valid Javascript: a response to a JSONP request must be valid Javascript. (To be precise, your code is invalid because the `{}` delimit a block, rather than an object literal.)

If you implement JSONP, you need to wrap the data in a call to a function whose name is given in the URL, in the `callback` parameter.  So in this case, you need to post the following code:

```js
jsonp1324336100888({
id: 6,
success: "true"
});
```

Obviously the precise name of the function you need to call depends on the `callback` URL parameter.

Comment: The code is _almost_ valid JSON: the property names should be (double)quoted for completely valid JSON. (JavaScript tends to forgive this since JS object literals can have unquoted property names.)